# Could not parse the remainder: '=='Sophia'' from 'abc.first_name=='Sophia'' Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to put an == sign inside an if statement in my html document (fourth line).

It looks like this:

```
    <ol>
        {% for league in teams %}
        {% for abc in league.curr_players.all %}
        {% if abc.first_name=='Sophia' %}
            <li>{{league.location}} {{league.team_name}} </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% empty %}
            <p>No leagues found.  Try <code>python manage.py loaddata data.json</code>, or, if that doesn't work, going <a href="{% url 'make_data' %}">here</a> (but be prepared to wait).</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
```

Anyways, I keep getting this error saying it can't parse the argument at that certain point.

Comment: In all documentations there are spaces around the operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template parser is pretty unsophisticated, unlike Python's. One consequence of this is that you need to use spaces around every operator.

```
{% if abc.first_name == 'Sophia' %}
```